# Verification of applications on Blackberry Store

Tags: blackberry

I need to know if the applications (contained in the blackberry store) are verified by blackberry before exposing them for downloads in the store.

Comment: -1 for not doing basic research before posting.

Comment: +1 because I think the steps of verification can be studied more rigorously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to help you prevent you from having to ask these type of basic answers. I will therefore show how to use Google and search for your answer:

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=blackberry+appstore+security

The first link yielded [this article](http://www.infosecurity-magazine.com/view/30593/blackberry-adds-app-store-security-to-weed-out-malware/)

> To prevent an Android-style malware overload from happening on its own
>   platform, and to find a big differentiator in the market, BlackBerry
>   has inked a deal with Trend Micro to add security for third-party
>   apps. All existing and new applications submitted to the BlackBerry
>   World storefront will be scanned for potential malicious behavior.
>
> To do that, BlackBerry is integrating Trend Micro’s Mobile Application
>   Reputation Service with its internal, proprietary system for analyzing
>   applications.
>
> "BlackBerry is working with Trend Micro to implement a more robust
>   approach for addressing privacy and security concerns related to
>   third-party applications," said Adrian Stone, director of BlackBerry
>   security response and threat analysis, in a statement. "By
>   incorporating Trend Micro's advanced mobile scanning and detection
>   capabilities with our own internal, proprietary application analyzing
>   system, we can provide another layer of protection and assurance for
>   BlackBerry customers.”
>
> "The volume of malicious and high-risk mobile apps is on the rise
>   across the industry,” said Kevin Simzer, vice president of corporate
>   development and alliances at Trend Micro. "With the speed that
>   cybercriminals are targeting new platforms and applications, Trend
>   Micro and BlackBerry's strategic collaboration is natural and timely
>   for the security of end users. Together, the two companies can further
>   secure and enhance BlackBerry customers' mobile experience."

Comment: It would be great to know how good is the system used for the task.